# Retrieving HTTP URLs using Perl scripting

Tags: html, perl, https

I'm trying to save the whole web page on my system as a `.html` file and then parse that file, to find some tags and use them.

I'm able to save/parse `http://<url>`, but not able to save/parse `https://<url>`. I'm using Perl.

I'm using the following code to save HTTP and it works fine but doesn't work for HTTPS:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 
use LWP::Simple qw($ua get);
use LWP::UserAgent;
use LWP::Protocol::https;
use HTTP::Cookies;

sub main
{
  my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();

  my $cookies = HTTP::Cookies->new(
    file => "cookies.txt",
    autosave => 1,
    );
 
  $ua->cookie_jar($cookies);
 
  $ua->agent("Google Chrome/30");
 

#$ua->ssl_opts( SSL_ca_file => 'cert.pfx' );

  $ua->proxy('http','http://proxy.com');
  my $response = $ua->get('http://google.com');

#$ua->credentials($response, "", "usrname", "password");
 
  unless($response->is_success) {
    print "Error: " . $response->status_line;
    }
 
         
    # Let's save the output.
  my $save = "save.html";
 
  unless(open SAVE, '>' . $save) {
    die "nCannot create save file '$save'n";
  }
 
    # Without this line, we may get a
    # 'wide characters in print' warning.
  binmode(SAVE, ":utf8");
 
  print SAVE $response->decoded_content;
 
  close SAVE;
 
  print "Saved ",
      length($response->decoded_content),
      " bytes of data to '$save'.";
}

main();
```

Is it possible to parse an HTTPS page?

Comment: any errors running this one-liner? `perl -MLWP::UserAgent -e '$ua=LWP::UserAgent->new;print $ua->get("https://github.com")->decoded_content();'`

Answer (score 5):

Always worth checking the documentation for the modules that you're using...

You're using modules from [libwww-perl](https://metacpan.org/release/libwww-perl). That includes [a cookbook](https://metacpan.org/module/GAAS/libwww-perl-6.05/lwpcook.pod). And in that cookbook, there is [a section about HTTPS](https://metacpan.org/module/GAAS/libwww-perl-6.05/lwpcook.pod), which says:

> URLs with https scheme are accessed in exactly the same way as with
>   http scheme, provided that an SSL interface module for LWP has been
>   properly installed (see the README.SSL file found in the libwww-perl
>   distribution for more details). If no SSL interface is installed for
>   LWP to use, then you will get "501 Protocol scheme 'https' is not
>   supported" errors when accessing such URLs.

The [README.SSL](https://metacpan.org/source/GAAS/libwww-perl-6.05/README.SSL) file says this:

> As of libwww-perl v6.02 you need to install the LWP::Protocol::https
>   module from its own separate distribution to enable support for
>   https://... URLs for LWP::UserAgent.

So you just need to install [LWP::Protocol::https](https://metacpan.org/release/LWP-Protocol-https).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have https://metacpan.org/module/Crypt::SSLeay for https links

It provides SSL support for LWP.

Bit me in the ass with a project of my own.

Comment: Actually in newer versions of [libwww-perl](https://metacpan.org/release/libwww-perl), you need to make sure that [LWP::Protocol::https](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP::Protocol::https) is installed ( installing it would force an SSL module to also be installed )